# Delete checked item from list view and data from database, using adapter class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
 public class delete extends BaseAdapter {
  SQLiteDatabase db;

String am;


 private final Context c;
private final ArrayList<String> str;
 private final String[] number;


ArrayList<Integer> checks=new ArrayList<Integer>();

public delete(Context c, ArrayList<String> str, String[] number, ArrayList<Integer> checks) {
    this.c = c;

    this.str = str;


    this.number = number;
    this.checks=checks;
}




@Override
public int getCount() {

    return str.size();


}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View ListView ;


    if(convertView==null)
    {
        ListView=new View(c);
        ListView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.button,null);

        TextView textview=(TextView) ListView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        textview.setText(str.get(position));



    }

    else
    {
        ListView=(View)convertView;
    }

    Button btnupdate=(Button)ListView.findViewById(R.id.button4);



      //checkbox declaration  
    CheckBox chk=(CheckBox)ListView.findViewById(R.id.chk1);




btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      db=c.openOrCreateDatabase("Student",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
      String num = number[position];
      Cursor cc=db.rawQuery("select mobile from detail where mobile='"+num+"'", null);

      if (cc.moveToFirst()) {
          do {


               am = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("mobile"));




             } while (cc.moveToNext());

      }



      Intent i=new Intent(c,Update.class);

      i.putExtra("value",am);
      c.startActivity(i);

  }



});













    return ListView;
  }



    }
```

//It show all the data in list view with update button and check box in list view. There is delete button which is suppose to delete all the item which is checked.
//Delete button is on main activity where list view is added.

Comment: what is a question in your "question" ?

Comment: I want to know how to delete the checked item from database, in listview.

Comment: see `SQLiteDatabase#delete`

Comment: I want to delete only item which is checked and that also from database. I am using custom listview.

Comment: i think nobody will want to read such badly formatted code... do something with it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your DataBase class and pass the table name and entry to be deleted along with id if any.Call the method at onClick of ListView item.

```
public void deleteEntry(String tableName,String columnName,String id)
          {
              openDatabase();
              database.delete(tableName, columnName + " = ?",new String[] { id });
              closeDatabase();
          }
```